# 000webhost Host is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql

This is my php code:

```
<?php
    try
    {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;dbname=database_name", 'xxxxxxxxx', '********');
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die($ex->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

Fairly simple, but I get:

```
Host 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

That is the ip of their server... Is the issue with my code or with the host?

EDIT:
Today i moved some of the files from 1 folder to another on the same server from the same account using FTP client. When i move them back it still doesn't work.
Also when i put the backup from yesterday everything works even though i use the same script to connect to the database and it's on the same place in every page.

Think it's something with the file permissions. Tried the little fix permissions option but it changed nothing. All my files have different permissions

Comment: Out of curiosity, never used 000webhost but I saw many questions similar to this, I wonder if either their documentation is poor, or wrong, or they work in an unusual way... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=000webhost+mysql

Comment: I'd ask them.  Maybe you entered the info incorrectly?  Should it be `localhost`?

Comment: Not possible. It was working yesterday with thiese parameters.

Comment: Please remember that all sites on StackExchange network are public, meaning anything you place here would be shown to to world wide web. Please refrain from posting any passwords, credit card numbers, access tokens, database credentials, or any other personal information of you or anyone else.

Comment: so if it was working yesterday, and now it doesn't then what do you expect people here to do to help you?  Clearly it is an issue with the host.  You need to get support from them.

Comment: i changed the place of the files a bit and then this appeared

Comment: @user2419750 Have you tried putting the files back where they were and check if it works then ?

Comment: Just tried and it still doesn't work. But if i put the backup from yesterday everything works. And my db connection function is the same... i have no idea what's up with that.

Comment: Your narrative is not reliable.  The information about the script working yesterday and you moving it, is not mentioned in the question at all.  You also don't provide any specifics about the move (from where to where?)  Did you move it from one server to another?  If so, then probably the ip of the mysql server/ not to mention the database and credentials could be entirely different.

Comment: I just moved it from 1 folder to another on the same server from the same account... i do not think it's that big of a deal

Comment: @user2419750 log into your 000webhost account, then go to your panel, then click on the MySQL Icon and you will see what you should use on the HOST option, its written in bold after this message `Important: MySQL Host for any database in this account is` and if you trying to use it remotely give up as remote access to the database is disabled unless you upgrade your account to the paid one.

Comment: I'm using the one from there... if i wasn't it wouldnt've worked yesterday
EDIT:
My bad. There was another one. Not sure if they've changed it today or something...

Answer (score 0):

if the php server and the mysql server is the same server, you should use "localhost".
because mysql differentiate between localhost and ip (eventhough it is the same ip address as the mysql server).
Or you can grant permission to a9783555_root@xx.xx.xx.xx

Comment: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'a9783555_root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
i get this when i use localhost

Comment: have you tried to connect to the mysql server directly? using console or phpmyadmin with the username/password?

Comment: I can access the db from phpmyadmin